# US Trademark Data

Tags: data-request, parsing, xml

Anyone have any experience working with US trademark  data? [Bulk data is easy to retrieve](https://bulkdata.uspto.gov), but it's challenging to work with. The assignments are small but need to be joined with other data to be interesting. And then the applications data sets are rather large (for my purposes) and the volume is quite high. I wasn't sure if there was an API that was a bit simpler to work with and thought someone here might have some experience.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case, you might be able to find an API on https://developer.uspto.gov/api-catalog.

If you already have a list of trademarks you want to check against, [The Trademark Status Document Retrieval](https://developer.uspto.gov/api-catalog/tsdr-data-api) API can fetch you their status.

But I don't think they have any API for raw queries, which is understandable because I can imagine that they want to deter patent trolls. Imagine someone querying for all misspellings of Disney, and trademarking anything which is still available.